# Lua: Find hex-value in string

Tags: lua, find, hex, design-patterns, non-printable

I'm trying to find the hexadecimal non-printable character 00h within a string with Lua. I tried it with an escape character and as a result I get the same location I start in (that's a printable character). I fiddled around with the character classes, but that didn't amount to anything. My approach looks like this:

```
location = string.find(variable,"\00",startlocation)
```

I also tried it this way, but no luck:

```
location = string.find(variable, string.char(00),startlocation)
```

How can I find this non-printable pattern in Lua?

Comment: Did you try `location = string.find(variable,"\0",startlocation)` with a single zero?

Comment: One, two or three zeros is the same thing.

Comment: shouldn't you use `%z` for zero characters in patterns (at least in 5.1) ?

Comment: Yes, I did that, too. I found my mistake. "variable" is filled 00h. I thought I started at a printable character, but in fact I didn't. That's why "location" ended up being the same value as "startlocation", leading me to believe I somehow didn't use the correct representation of 00h in the string.find-command. Thanks to lhf for actually leading me to the right conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine for me:

```
> return string.find("one\0two\0,three","\0,")
8   9
> return string.find("one\0two\0,three","\0")
4   4
> return string.find("one\0two\0,three","\00")
4   4
> return string.find("one\0two\0,three","\00",6)
8   8
```

Comment: Hmm, must be an error in my code then. I need to check the other variables.

Comment: @Zerobinary99, `string.char(00)` returns a string of length 1 whose only byte is 0 and this is exactly what `"\0"` is. Try `print(string.char(00)=="\0")`.

Comment: I just tested that out myself ;) Hence the edit of my initial message. Thought I could correct my false assumption before you saw it, but you were faster ;)

Comment: Note that \0 isn't valid in a pattern in lua 5.1; use %z.